# Align a button in top of a div

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align a button to the top of a div, but it's not working.

This is my html

```
<div id='deleteOutDiv'><div class='deleteInnerDiv'><a class=\"delete iconBtn\" onclick=\"deleteResourceItem(#: ID #, '#: Naam #')\"></a></div></div>
```

and this is my css

```
   #deleteOutDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#deleteOutDiv .deleteInnerDiv {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

This is what it looks like on my Kendo Grid[image]

This is the html and css for the other cells, which works.

```
 <div id='editDiv'><div class='inputDiv'><textarea class='textEdit' cols='50' rows='3'>#=Naam#</textarea></div><div class='editorDiv'><a class=\"meerActies iconBtn\" onclick=\"openPopupDemo('#: Naam #', '#: ID #', 'Naam')\"></a></div></div>


#editDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#editDiv .inputDiv {
     display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
}

#editDiv .editorDiv {
     display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
}

#editDiv .textEdit {
     background: transparent;
     border: none;
     resize:none;
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` only works on elements that are `display: table;` / `display: table-cell;` i believe

Answer (score 0):

Using your code above, try the following:

```
#deleteOutDiv {
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Looks like you're missing the `display: inline-block;` which is being used in the other `div` tags :)

Comment: Did anything change at all?

Comment: No, nothing. Strange thing is that it works in jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you link your fiddle?

Comment: That fiddle isn't a representation of your issue, and it's not working there as far as i can see